# Segue to specific segment controller index

Tags: ios, button, segue, uisegmentedcontrol

I have 3 buttons on VC1. I want to segue to VC2 which has a segmented controller. My question is can I segue to a specific segmented controller index? If so, how can I do this?

I have recreated a basic looking UI which simulated my actual app.[image]

Comment: Not seeing what I need in that link.

Comment: The question is: How do I tell my next viewcontroller to behave differently according to some param I set (ie. if I tap first, second or third button). You have to create a variable in next viewcontroller, and set it on `prepareForSegue:`. On loading, next viewcontroller read it and choose the selected index needed for the segmented control.

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks.